# Will the Ontario HST rebates be direct deposited, or mailed, or both in June 2010 and 2011?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

Will the Ontario HST rebates be direct deposited, or mailed, or both in June 2010 and 2011?

Comment: See http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/ontario-hst-rebate-what-was-the-mailing-date-of-the-june-2011-hst-rebate-cheque for June 2011.

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/families.html#transitionpay) it depends on your previous income tax return(s).

If you have direct deposit set up, you will receive your payment there.  Otherwise a cheque will be mailed.