# Ontario HST Rebate: What was the mailing date of the June, 2011 HST rebate cheque?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate

What was the date that the June, 2011 HST rebate cheques were mailed?

I have my bank statement that covers up to June 17th and the HST cheque was not deposited by that time.

Answer (score 4):

The Ontario Government mailed the June, 2011 HST cheques **early**, likely at the end of May or early June, in anticipation of rotating strikes by Canada Post workers.

However, the cheques were [post-dated for June 10th](http://www.yorkregion.com/news/article/1021191--wait-to-cash-hst-cheques-province).

If you didn't receive your rebate yet, [this other answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/ontario-hst-rebate-i-didnt-get-my-rebate-what-phone-number-can-i-call) points to contact information.